# Which was the first novel set in universes where P=NP?

Tags: history-of, hard-sci-fi, mathematics

I wonder whether anyone has written a novel set in a universe where [`P=NP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), in the event that there is more than one, which was the first?

[image]

In this universe all problems that could be verified in polynomial time (NP) (given the solution) could also be solved in polynomial time (P).

Comment: for good reason, I'd imagine. I can see the dialogue right now.

Comment: Greg Egan wrote Dark integers and Luminous which are about calculability and complexity in a pure a algebra settings. If that can work, so can a novel about P=NP :)

Comment: The [MathFiction Homepage](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/) would be a good starting point for something like this.

Comment: Not a novel, but Russell Impagliazzo (a top complexity theory researcher) wrote a short paper describing five worlds in which such things happen (the Algorithmica universe has P = NP, Cryptomania has guaranteed public-key cryptography, etc.). Just thought I'd mention in case you're curious for a more theoretical viewpoint on what a world with P = NP would look like. http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2004/06/impagliazzos-five-worlds.html

Comment: Dr G +1, but I'm not sure what versions of Egan's short stories you've read :P but I took it as being that truth values of arithmetic statements were behaving like the spin of a quantum particle, and the calculation of mathematical results was flipping these truth values, to the detriment of an 'other, parallel universe'. Physics itself was affected by changing the rules of maths, so there was chaos all-round when the 'others' fought back. (And yes, I have a PhD in pure maths)

Comment: ...and how do you know P=NP isn't true our universe? Let me know and I'll share the $1m with you.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I should have phrased the question as a novel set in a universe where we know P=NP :) Re:Egan, I interpreted the story as a twist on intensional definition. Our theory is based on intensional definition, doesn't mean that the universe agrees, and since we haven't tried to verify the extensional version of our definitions the physical universe might disagree.

Comment: Maybe all of them... Since it's an unsolved problem at this moment. :-)

Comment: Can you explain, in *really* simple terms, what P=NP means and how we'd know if a book we're reading would be in that universe?

Comment: @Wikis: In a P=NP universe _finding_ a correct solution to a large and well defined hierarchy of problems would be only as complex as _recognizing_ that a proposed solution to such a problem is correct.  For example, in our universe recognizing that a work of art is great seems to be much easier than creating a great work.  In a universe where P=NP the amount of effort required would be the same or only modestly greater when looked at in terms of the size of the problem to be solved.  Easy cracking of almost all forms of encryption is another sign of a P=NP universe.

Comment: @DrG: Greg Egan could probably write a novel where P and NP are the protagonists. That guy makes Kim Stanley Robinson look like George Lucas.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Antibodies, Charles Stross, 2000

A short story that hinges on the fact that solving P=NP is a required prerequisite for developing a computer intelligence. It's available in his book *[Toast](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1587154137)*. Stross has put the [full text](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/toast/toast-intro.html) of this book online. ([This link](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/toast/toast.html#antibodies) will take you directly to the story.)

And according to Stross's site, the story was:

> Published in Interzone #157; republished in "The Year's Best Science Fiction #18" (ed. Gardner Dozois). Mentioned in Locus' "Recommended Reading List" for 2000.
>   Shortlisted for the 2001 Theodore Sturgeon Award (lost to Ian MacDonald's "Tendoleo's Story").

Answer (score 81):

Star Trek, Various, 1966 (earliest occurrence)

P=NP in the Star Trek universe, but the people there aren't aware of it.  **Evidence:**

1. There is encryption but it is *always* breakable.  P=NP will let you crack everything but one-time pads but the Federation stubbornly continues to use NP-based ciphers.
2. The efficacy of the universal translator.  P=NP would make learning new languages a breeze, at least for a computer.  Learning systems would be so simple and straightforward to implement that there wouldn't be a linguist left with a job.
3. The efficacy of the bio-filter.  The transporter routinely filters unknown organisms, viruses and other hazards when crewmen are beamed aboard ship.  But "bio-filter" is a misleading term as it brings to mind some sort of sieve that catches all the bad stuff and passes only the good.  In reality running such a "filter" over transport data would be the mother of all [induced subgraph isomorphism problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph_isomorphism_problem), as you would have to identify all virus-sized structures in an organism chock-full of such structures.  P=NP magicks away the input-related exponent that makes such problems intractable even for small graphs.
4. Self-aware machine intelligence is created with ease.  Wesley Crusher created one by accident.  So did Richard Daystrom.  The Enterprise D computer cooked up Moriarty in its spare cycles, Dr. Farallon created the Exocomps, and so on.  All you seem to need to do is build something equivalent to a theorem proving system and let it run long enough to stumble over the proof that P or some other tractable class is equivalent to NP and the system is off to the races.

Or perhaps the Star Trek denizens are collapsing the polynomial hierarchy by technological means.  The Federation, Borg, etc. seem to have ready access to time machines, wormholes, exotic matter, and superluminal signalling, so they could be using closed time-like curves for computation.  This [according to Scott Aaronson](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec19.html) would allow them efficiently solve PSPACE-complete problems.

Comment: +1 for using evidence from the world to show some thing. Most Excellent.

Comment: I think they merely tackle the three points you issue by raw computing power. A DTM can solve precisely the same problems as an NTM, but it takes longer. So, if their engineering skills are mad enough, they can cough up really fast (parallel) computers (also they probably found a couple of nice heuristics for some NP-hard problems along the way). So, I'm not sure how your arguments apply.

Comment: @Blue  
Perhaps I should have written P=NP lets you crack everything _useful_ but one-time pads. If you can't verify decryption in polynomial time, which is what having a cryptosystem outside NP means, then _even with the key_ decryption is not computationally feasible. That to me is not a useful cryptosystem.

Comment: @bitmask: It's somewhere in the Tech Manuals that Star Trek runs the computer core inside a modified warp field where time runs at a different rate.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: If there *are* problem solving techniques strictly more powerful than a very fast DTM, and for practical applications P and NP have lost relevance, that by itself is very strong evidence for P=NP in the universe.  In a P!=NP universe the discovery of such techniques is very unlikely.

Comment: @Tynam P and NP are defined strictly in terms of what is possible to do with deterministic and non-deterministic Turnig machines; it simply makes no sense to talk about them outside of that context. There's already evidence that quantum computers *might* provide a way to perform non-deterministic computations, for example...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Good point; I hadn't thought through the quantum computer / NDTM angle.  That said, the practical difference between a P=NP universe and a significantly-more-powerful-ND-computing universe seems likely to be small.
(But then, I'm not convinced the human brain is meaningfully more powerful than a DTM; parallelism isn't the same thing as algorithmic complexity.)

Comment: Could you put a date to this?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Date to what?

Comment: @Kyle the date at which you think there star trek series was first portrayed as P=NP.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Choosing from my examples I think it would have to be the first episode featuring use of the universal translator in a first contact situation.  In TOS that would be episode 10 of the first season, "The Corbomite Maneuver" when *Enterprise* encountered Baalok and the First Federation fun ball.

Comment: @kyle that makes it 1966, which is a contender. Would you be opposed to me editing it into your answer?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage nope, go ahead.

Answer (score 26):

The other Stross book that deals with this is [The Atrocity Archives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Atrocity_Archives), where Alan Turing solved P=NP, but they then found that doing so allowed access to the Cthonic Realms, so now an entire branch of Government exists to prevent this discovery becoming public knowledge.

Answer (score 19):

In Vernor Vinges "Zones of Thought" series ("The Blabber", *A Fire Upon the Deep*, *A Deepness in the Sky* and the forthcoming *The Children of the Sky*), computation is easier in some parts of the galaxy, allowing for things like artificial intelligence and FTL travel.

It has been speculated (but there's no direct evidence in the books) that `P=NP` in these zones.

Comment: Is there any indirect evidence? My recollection is that computation is different outside the Slow Zone (Church's thesis only holds in the Slow Zone) and something like P=NP needn't apply or even make sense there.

Comment: In *A Fire Upon the Deep* the Skode Riders find Pham's belief in public key encryption to be humorous. From that we can conclude that `P == NP` in the Beyond.

Comment: Not necessarily -- quantum computers could theoretically handle NP-complete problems in polynomial time, even without P=NP.

Comment: No, they cannot.  The operations that the most widespread public-key encryption algorithms rely on being difficult - factoring, discrete log - are not (believed to be) NP-complete.  These are the problems that quantum computers are theoretically able to break in polynomial time.  That being said, there are public-key encryption algorithms that *are* based on NP-complete problems, but these are not in widespread use (yet...)

Comment: @BlueRaja We currently know no way to use a quantum computer to solve NP complete problems efficiently, but you're asserting that `P < NP <= BQP` is false, and I know of no proof for this. I agree that it's likely false, but you state it as a fact.

Comment: @Code: Yes, sorry I didn't speak carefully.  I meant it's *not* known (or believed) to be theoretically possible.

Comment: I was going to say Zones of Thought. I'm not sure it's literally true that P=NP, in that it's possible that _at any particular location in a zone_, our intuition that you can construct an NP problem you can't easily solve holds true. But I think it's similar enough to be worth mentioning, in that you can move (or send a message) to a higher zone, where your problem will be easily solvable.

Answer (score 5):

In the fanfic [Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality](http://www.fanfiction.net/s/5782108/1/Harry_Potter_and_the_Methods_of_Rationality) by Eliezer S. Yudkowsky, Harry gets a time machine and tries to [factor the product of two large prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) using this machine, with a somewhat weird result. So it is not completely given that `NP=P`, but seems probable.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A problem belongs into P, if a certain Turing machine solving this problem exists (definition of NP is similar). It doesn't matter whether there are other conceivable means of solving this problem. By hacking time loops Harry got beyond P=NP question.

Comment: Yes, if his test was successful, it would have meant that there is a 'stronger' computation device than the Turing machine and therefore he disproved Church's thesis. So if you leave NP defined using Turing machines, it wouldn't prove 'NP = P'.

Comment: IIRC, it has been proven that P=PSPACE (which is stronger than P=NP) for a Turing machine equipped with the ability to send data backward in time, even if it's subject to Novikov self-consistency.  It is still possible that P=PSPACE for ordinary Turing machines, but this is considered even less plausible than P=NP by 'mainstream' complexity theorists.

Answer (score 3):

*The Roaring Trumpet* by Spague de Camp and Fletcher Pratt, published in May 1940 in Unknown. Here, psychologists posit that schizophrenics are actually mentally accessing alternate universes, and by applying the proper equations, one could travel to that alternate universe and bring the persons mind back to our universe. It was an intellectual exercise which the main protagonist Harold Shea decides to test out. He jokingly refers to travel via syllogismobile, but it involves studying and constructing the logic of the universe destination and reciting it out loud. This generally begins with "if P is equal to not P..." And goes from there. The entire Enchanter series has them universe hopping through mythology and fairy tale and classical works by doing so.

I suspect, never having given it any real thought, that by prefacing with P=NP, they were distinguishing the universe as one in which magic functions.

Comment: "NP" in "P = NP" does not mean "not P", however. The phrasing could be based on a misunderstanding, but I'm sure the P vs. NP problem was not formulated by 1940, so they probably just meant to assert a contradiction ("P" being a generic proposition; by assuming P and not P, anything can follow.) AFAIK the P vs NP question was first posed as such in 1971.

Answer (score 1):

Nemesis, Isaac Asimov, 1989

It talks about imposibilities and the implications of an universe where the laws of physics doesn't apply

Comment: Please provide a date with your answer, next time and explain why this relates *explicitly* to P=NP.

Answer (score 1):

*[The practice effect](http://www.davidbrin.com/practiceeffect1.htm)*, David Brin, 1984

This seems a likely candidate. In the depicted universe, a robotic probe from our universe starts to self-optimize both physically and mentally while the human intelligence remains unaltered. Also physical objects tend to self-optimize: a wooden sleigh develops lubricant to easily slide on the road. This practice effect can be boosted by a special state of trance where the solution appears immediately by itself, hence inanimate objects perform a wide-range evolution within non-polynomial time (Seeking a near infinite array of posible solutions within a short period of time). This universe actually transcends P=NP.

Comment: Please [edit] in why you think this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In the story *Starshield Sentinels* by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman, there were computers/artificial intelligences that could answer any question *instantly* by sending the question back in time to itself, giving it 'time' to solve it. The only hiccup to this was that the computer had to be 'awake' long enough to solve it (something like Deep Thought from The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy needing 10 million years to solve the question to life, the universe, and everything).

While I don't know if this exactly pertains to everything P = NP, it does solve the variable/solve clause in the question.

Of course the computers all go nuts and try to kill everyone in the story. Can't we stop trying to invent killer robots now?

Answer (score -2):

If I'm not mistaken, in Bob Shaw's '[The Ragged Astronauts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671654055)', one of the characters spends a bit of time explaining how pi is 3 to another. If pi is 3, I can only imagine what the rest of the physics is like. (I only remember the scene at all because the whole scene was a bit out of place, which was pretty unusual for the book - otherwise it was a neat tale).

Comment: How does this relate to p=np?